# Is there a neat approach to label a ggplot plot with the equation and other statistics from geom_quantile()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, quantile-regression, ggpmisc

I'd like to include the relevant statistics from a `geom_quantile()` fitted line in a similar way to how I would for a `geom_smooth(method="lm")` fitted linear regression (where I've previously used **ggpmisc** which is [awesome](https://github.com/aphalo/ggpmisc)). For example, this code:

```
# quantile regression example with ggpmisc equation
# basic quantile code from here:
# https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_quantile.html

library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)
# see ggpmisc vignette for stat_poly_eq() code below:
# https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpmisc/vignettes/user-guide.html#stat_poly_eq

my_formula <- y ~ x
#my_formula <- y ~ poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)

# linear ols regression with equation labelled
m <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, 1 / hwy)) +
  geom_point()

m + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = my_formula) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label =  paste(stat(eq.label), "*\" with \"*", 
                                  stat(rr.label), "*\", \"*", 
                                  stat(f.value.label), "*\", and \"*",
                                  stat(p.value.label), "*\".\"",
                                  sep = "")),
               formula = my_formula, parse = TRUE, size = 3)
```

generates this:
[image: ggplot with linear ols equation]

For a quantile regression, you can swap out `geom_smooth()` for `geom_quantile()` and get a lovely quantile regression line plotted (in this case the median):

```
# quantile regression - no equation labelling
m + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles = 0.5)
```

[image: geom_quantile plot]

How would you get the summary statistics out to a label, or recreate them on the go? (i.e. other than doing the regression prior to the call to ggplot and then passing it in to then annotate (e.g. similar to what was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61266646/4927395) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61363645/4927395) for a linear regression?

Comment: What are the specific "relevant statistics" that you would like to print on the plot? Of course its always best to fit your own model to get important fit statistics rather replying on a plotting function. Those other functions are basically just wrappers that do that for you (you end up fitting the model multiple times which is a bit wasteful). You could write your own geom to do this if you really want to hide the work but that's basically what needs to happen.

Comment: Fair call. I think there may be a solution using `stat_fit_glance` from **ggpmisc**, though I just need to get my head around how it might work with multiple quantiles. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpmisc/vignettes/user-guide.html#stat_fit_glance

Comment: I was hoping `stat_fit_glance()` and `stat_fit_tidy()` would allow me to replace the 'lm' method with 'rq' and I would be done. No such luck. For an alternative approach, it is easy to make the tibbles of summary statistics for `quantreg::rq()`outside the ggplot call, though `glance()` requires the use of `purrr::map` when multiple quantiles are desired.

Comment: @MarkNeal I have raised an issue to remind myself of having a look at why `stat_fit_glance()` does not work if `glance()` is implemented. (And thanks for letting me know that you find 'ggpmisc' useful!)

Comment: @MarkNeal The new 'ggpmisc' 0.3.8 is now in CRAN. I have updated my answer based on this version. Now it is possible to add the equation and _p_-value of the model fitted with `qr()` using `stat_fit_tidy()`.

Comment: @MarkNeal The next release of 'ggpmisc', version 0.4.0 is taking shape in GitHub. I have added `stat_quant_eq()`. It tries to provide an elegant answer to your question including support for a vector of quantiles. If you can find some time for it, could you check and give feedback?
You will need to install from GitHub packages 'ggpp' and 'gppmisc':
`remotes::install_github("aphalo/ggpp")` and `remotes::install_github("aphalo/ggpmisc", ref = "stat.quant.eq")` .
The `ref` argument points to the branch where the new stat has been implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package 'ggpmisc' (>= 0.4.5) allows a much simpler answer, which is closer to the solution hoped for by @MarkNeal in his question about median regression. This answer should be preferred to earlier ones when using a recent version of 'ggpmisc'. Not shown: passing `se = FALSE` to `stat_quant_line()` disables the confidence band.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
#> Loading required package: ggpp
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggpp'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     annotate

m <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, 1 / hwy)) +
  geom_point()

m + 
  stat_quant_line(quantiles = 0.5) +
  stat_quant_eq(aes(label =  paste(after_stat(eq.label), "*\" with \"*", 
                                   after_stat(rho.label), "*\", \"*", 
                                   after_stat(n.label), "*\".\"",
                                   sep = "")),
                quantiles = 0.5,
                size = 3)  
#> Warning in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ci = TRUE, ...): Solution may be nonunique
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The default is to plot the median and quartiles.

```r
m + 
  stat_quant_line() +
  stat_quant_eq(aes(label =  paste(after_stat(eq.label), "*\" with \"*", 
                                   after_stat(rho.label), "*\", \"*", 
                                   after_stat(n.label), "*\".\"",
                                   sep = "")),
                size = 3)  
#> Warning in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ci = TRUE, ...): Solution may be nonunique
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

We can also map the quantiles to `color` and `linetype` aesthetics easily.

```r
m + 
  stat_quant_line(aes(linetype = after_stat(quantile.f),
                  color = after_stat(quantile.f))) +
  stat_quant_eq(aes(label =  paste(after_stat(eq.label), "*\" with \"*", 
                                   after_stat(rho.label), "*\", \"*", 
                                   after_stat(n.label), "*\".\"",
                                   sep = ""),
                    color = after_stat(quantile.f)),
                size = 3)  
#> Warning in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ci = TRUE, ...): Solution may be nonunique
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

We can also plot the quartiles as a band by using `stat_quant_band()` instead of `stat_quant_line()`.

```r
m + 
  stat_quant_band() +
  stat_quant_eq(aes(label =  paste(after_stat(eq.label), "*\" with \"*", 
                                   after_stat(rho.label), "*\", \"*", 
                                   after_stat(n.label), "*\".\"",
                                   sep = "")),
                size = 3)  
#> Warning in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ci = TRUE, ...): Solution may be nonunique
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Please consider this an appendix to Pedro's excellent answer, where he did most of the heavy lifting - this adds some presentation tweaks (colour and linetype) and code to simplify multiple quantiles, producing the plot below:

[image: quantile plot]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc) #ensure version 0.3.8 or greater
library(quantreg)
library(generics)

my_formula <- y ~ x
#my_formula <- y ~ poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)

# base plot
m <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, 1 / hwy)) +
  geom_point()

# function for labelling
# Doesn't neatly handle P values (e.g return "P<0.001 where appropriate)

stat_rq_eqn <- function(formula = y ~ x, tau = 0.5, colour = "red", label.y = 0.9, ...) {
  stat_fit_tidy(method = "rq",
                method.args = list(formula = formula, tau = tau), 
                tidy.args = list(se.type = "nid"),
                mapping = aes(label = sprintf('italic(tau)~"="~%.3f~";"~y~"="~%.3g~+~%.3g~x*", with "~italic(P)~"="~%.3g',
                                              after_stat(x_tau),
                                              after_stat(Intercept_estimate), 
                                              after_stat(x_estimate),
                                              after_stat(x_p.value))),
                parse = TRUE,
                colour = colour,
                label.y = label.y,
                ...)
}

# This works, though with double entry of plot specs
# custom colours and linetype
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383810/4927395
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/64518380/4927395


m + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9), 
                aes(colour = as.factor(..quantile..),
                    linetype = as.factor(..quantile..))
                )+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red","purple","darkgreen"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dotted", "dashed", "solid"))+
  stat_rq_eqn(tau = 0.1, colour = "red", label.y = 0.9)+
  stat_rq_eqn(tau = 0.5, colour = "purple", label.y = 0.95)+
  stat_rq_eqn(tau = 0.9, colour = "darkgreen", label.y = 1.0)+
  theme(legend.position = "none") # suppress legend


# not a good habit to have double entry above
# modified with reference to tibble for plot specs, 
# though still a stat_rq_eqn call for each quantile and manual vertical placement
# https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/06/curly-curly-the-successor-of-bang-bang/

my_tau = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9)
my_colours = c("red","purple","darkgreen")
my_linetype = c("dotted", "dashed", "solid")

quantile_plot_specs <- tibble(my_tau, my_colours, my_linetype)

m + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles = {{quantile_plot_specs$my_tau}}, 
                aes(colour = as.factor(..quantile..),
                    linetype = as.factor(..quantile..))
  )+
  scale_color_manual(values = {{quantile_plot_specs$my_colours}})+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = {{quantile_plot_specs$my_linetype}})+
  stat_rq_eqn(tau = {{quantile_plot_specs$my_tau[1]}}, colour = {{quantile_plot_specs$my_colours[1]}}, label.y = 0.9)+
  stat_rq_eqn(tau = {{quantile_plot_specs$my_tau[2]}}, colour = {{quantile_plot_specs$my_colours[2]}}, label.y = 0.95)+
  stat_rq_eqn(tau = {{quantile_plot_specs$my_tau[3]}}, colour = {{quantile_plot_specs$my_colours[3]}}, label.y = 1.0)+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 2):

@mark-neal `stat_fit_glance()` does work with `quantreg::rq()`. Using `stat_fit_glance()`is however more involved. This stat does not "know" what to expect from `glance()`, so one has to assemble the `label` manually.

One needs to know what is available for this. One can either run fit the model outside the ggplot and use `glance()` to find out what columns it returns or one can do this in the ggplot with the help of package 'gginnards'. I will show this alternative, continuing from your code example above.

```r
library(gginnards)

m + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles = 0.5) +
  stat_fit_glance(method = "rq", method.args = list(formula = y ~ x), geom = "debug")
```

`geom_debug()` by default just prints its input to the R console, its input is what the statistics returns.

```
# A tibble: 1 x 11
   npcx  npcy   tau logLik    AIC    BIC df.residual     x      y PANEL group
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>       <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <fct> <int>
1    NA    NA   0.5   816. -1628. -1621.         232  1.87 0.0803 1        -1
```

We can the access each of this columns using `after_stat()` (earlier incarnations being `stat()` and enclosing the names `...`. We need to do the formatting using the encoding notation of `sprintf()`. If as in this case we assemble a string that needs to be parsed into an expression, `parse = TRUE` is also needed.

```r
m + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles = 0.5) +
  stat_fit_glance(method = "rq", method.args = list(formula = y ~ x), 
                  mapping = aes(label = sprintf('italic(tau)~"="~%.2f~~AIC~"="~%.3g~~BIC~"="~%.3g',
                                                after_stat(tau), after_stat(AIC), after_stat(BIC))),
                  parse = TRUE)
```

This example results in the following plot.
[image]

With `stat_fit_tidy()` the same approach should have worked. However, in 'ggpmisc' (<= 0.3.7) it worked with "lm" but not with "rq". This bug is fixed in 'ggpmisc' (>= 0.3.8), now in CRAN.

**The example below works only with 'ggpmisc' (>= 0.3.8)**

The remaining questions is whether the `tibble` that `glance()` or `tidy()` return contains the information one wants to add to the plot, which does not seem to be the case for `tidy.qr()`, at least by default. However, `tidy.rq()` has a parameter `se.type` that determines the values returned in the `tibble`. The revised `stat_fit_tidy()` accepts named arguments to be passed to `tidy()`, making the following possible.

```r
m + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles = 0.5) +
  stat_fit_tidy(method = "rq",
                method.args = list(formula = y ~ x), 
                tidy.args = list(se.type = "nid"),
                mapping = aes(label = sprintf('y~"="~%.3g~+~%.3g~x*", with "*italic(P)~"="~%.3f',
                                              after_stat(Intercept_estimate), 
                                              after_stat(x_estimate),
                                              after_stat(x_p.value))),
                parse = TRUE)
```

This example results in the following plot.

[image]

Defining a new stat `stat_rq_eq()` would make this even simpler:

```r
stat_rq_eqn <- function(formula = y ~ x, tau = 0.5, ...) {
  stat_fit_tidy(method = "rq",
                method.args = list(formula = formula, tau = tau), 
                tidy.args = list(se.type = "nid"),
                mapping = aes(label = sprintf('y~"="~%.3g~+~%.3g~x*", with "*italic(P)~"="~%.3f',
                                              after_stat(Intercept_estimate), 
                                              after_stat(x_estimate),
                                              after_stat(x_p.value))),
                parse = TRUE,
                ...)
}
```

With the answer becoming:

```r
m + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles = 0.5) +
  stat_rq_eqn(tau = 0.5)
```

Comment: For those new to it, adding `tau=0.9` within the `stat_fit_tidy()` gives the 90th quantile equation to the plot to match `geom_quantile(quantiles = 0.9)` which would produce the line. If no tau value is defined, it defaults to 0.5 (i.e. a "median" regression).

Comment: A "joined-up" handling of multiple quantile equations could allow the labels to "step" vertically so that a manual y axis location doesn't need to be specified to avoid overlap. I'm going to look into incorporating some code to print `P<0.01` which is tidier than rounding to zero or providing a ridiculously small number in scientific notation. In any case, thumbs up for Pedro getting this working!

Comment: @MarkNeal The code for the P-value is in the source of `stat_poly_eq()` and could be copied from there. Given that most likely I will be also using this, I will try to add support for multiple values of tau before the next release. Thinking how I would use it myself, it could make sense to also have a stat_quantile_band() that would plot the quantiles like stat_smooth() plots the confidence band. Would this be useful? Although one can map ...tau... to color or linetype this could interfere with other uses of these aesthetics.

Comment: I can see the confidence bands being very useful for 1 to 3 quantiles, but a larger number of quantiles would have too much overlap to be useful (I think). For audiences with some exposure to quantile regression, mapping visually with line type or colour is redundant; labelling the equation with ‘tau=0.9’ is sufficient and it is obvious that is the ‘highest’ line of it is the highest tau value.

Comment: @MarkNeal I have implemented statistic `stat_quant_eq()` in what is going to be the next release of 'ggpmisc'. It supports a vector for quantiles (= tau).  I used `quantiles` instead of tau to be consistent with `stat_quantile()`. I did some testing and it seems to be working as expected. I still need to test use of facets. As I also split 'ggpmisc' into two packages, installation from GitHub can be done using:
`remotes::install_github("aphalo/ggpp")` followed by `remotes::install_github("aphalo/ggpmisc")`. 

If possible, try it and let me know if it is buggy or needs improvements.

Comment: Will give it a run in the next couple of days, thanks for implementing!

Comment: Thanks! I will wait for your comments and do some additional checking myself before submission to CRAN.